# CFWriteStreamCanAcceptBytes Blocking

Tags: iphone, objective-c, macos, networking, bonjour

I have created a program which can send one image from my iPhone to my Mac successfully. Problem being as soon as this has finished sending, I want to send some other data (exactly what is irrelevant). Whenever I try to send data, I am blocked by the following line:

```
if ( !CFWriteStreamCanAcceptBytes((CFWriteStreamRef)_outputStream) ) {
    NSLog(@"FAILED ErrorCode:2 saveAsWallpaper in server.m");
    return;
}
```

I do not close any streams, or anything of the sort. I thought the problem may be with the following line:

```
CFWriteStreamSetProperty(writeStream,kCFStreamPropertyShouldCloseNativeSocket,
                                     kCFBooleanFalse);
```

But that should prevent the socket from closing. I can provide more code if needed but I am hoping for more pointers in the right direction than a solution.

Any help welcome,
thanks!

Comment: Is there any way to print out additional information as to why I am getting blocked, e.g. NSError of sorts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turned out that turning off ARC somehow helped. Lines like this were not working correctly with it on (since it requires manual memory management from the looks of it):

```
if (kCFSocketSuccess != CFSocketSetAddress(_socket, (CFDataRef)CFBridgingRetain(address4))) {
```

Note the word "Retain".

Not a solution for everyone, but turning off ARC then managing the leaks myself got everything working fine for my project.

Comment: hi just to clarify, and then CFWriteStreamCanAcceptBytes worked correctly? - I left ARC on and added a connection check at the beginning of my communication while during communication I dont check that anymore

Comment: user387184, yes. There must have been an object somewhere which was required that ARC was abandoning too early. Managing my own memory has since helped, though I'm now having to learn how to manage memory!

Comment: I tried now without ARC, haveing created a special communication class only doing CFWriteStreamCanAcceptBytes getting passed the writeStream - that does not work either, no idea why?

Comment: user387184, I think my solution was specific to my code. I'd recommend checking out the programming guide from Apple here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Conceptual/CFNetwork/CFStreamTasks/CFStreamTasks.html and if that doesn't help check out their example. Alternatively, open up a question and see if anyone can help you out. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

there seems to be a bug (or at least an inconsistency) with that method on the new iPhone5. The very same CFWriteStreamCanAcceptBytes works perfectly on iPhone 3GS but not on iPhone5.

The only solution I found so far does not use `CFWriteStreamCanAcceptBytes` anymore and just writes - this works fine.

The only issue with that is that the timeout takes about 20-30 secs once the connection is lost and you write anyway.

To handle that the very first time you can perform the write in another task using `performSelectorInBackground` and check if it took too long to return, then you can be sure that the connection is lost and set your own flag which can be used as a gate keeper for subsequent calls to write.

But in 99% of the cases it works OK, since the connection is OK.

I tried many alternatives but there is no way to stop the `write` execution once it has started - so this is why I used `performSelectorInBackground`.

Even a timer which is supposed to execute in 5 secs has to wait since the write without success takes its time and does not accept any interruptions at all.

Comment: Ah, I appreciate the response and that is something I will have to consider later on - but I'm working on an iPhone 4. I didn't realize different models would be affected though, that is interesting. Point for a good answer though, thank you kindly.

Comment: Also, I did try not using CFWriteStreamCanAcceptBytes but instead the write stream returns 0, which apparently means "0 if the stream has been filled to capacity (for fixed-length streams)" according to the documentation.